# GPU server freezes during GPU idling

Tags: ubuntu, server-crashes, nvidia, freeze

We have a new Supermicro Server AS-4124GS-TNR equipped with eight NVIDIA RTX A6000. The OS is Ubuntu 20.04.2, the NVIDIA driver version is 460.73.01 (no Nouveau driver used), the CUDA Version is 11.2.

We ran a few long-lasting tests on the GPUs and the system was stable. However, after some GPU idling the system crashed repeatedly.

We assume that `GpuPowerMizerMode` has to be set to 1 to prevent crashes during GPU idling (an assumption backed by other user reports found on the internet).

The only way to do this that we know of is to start X (e.g. by starting gdm) and then set the value accordingly via `nvidia-settings` (running `nvidia-settings` without X/gdm leads to "*Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused.*"). But when stopping X/gdm, the `GpuPowerMizerMode` value is automatically reset to 2. Unfortunately, keeping X/gdm running is not an option because this also leads to system instability.

So, our problem seems to be as follows:

1. GPU idling + `GpuPowerMizerMode` != 1 can result in a system freeze. `GpuPowerMizerMode` can only be set via `nvidia-settings` connected to a running X/dm(?). In order to persistently set the value to 1 X/dm(?) has to keep running.
2. A running X/gdm can cause a system crash.

Are our assumptions correct? / Are others also experiencing these specific problems?

How can we solve the problem of freezing during GPU idling?

Answer (score 1):

It should not be necessary to start a GUI session (or even have one installed!) to change settings such as this; `nvidia-settings` should work fine from the framebuffer console or even in a script you write that runs at startup.

Check to be sure:

```
# nvidia-settings -q GpuPowerMizerMode

  Attribute 'GPUPowerMizerMode' (blacktemple:1[gpu:0]): 1.
    Valid values for 'GPUPowerMizerMode' are: 0, 1 and 2.
    'GPUPowerMizerMode' can use the following target types: GPU.
```

For eight GPUs just write a simple script, something like:

```
for n in $(seq 0 7); do
    nvidia-settings -a "[gpu:$n]/GpuPowerMizerMode=1"
done
```

and run it at startup in whatever manner you find convenient.

---

I can't say whether your crashes are due to running with GpuPowerMizerMode!=1. If that is the case, then you probably have some sort of defective hardware that you should track down and replace.

Comment: Running nvidia-settings without running and using X/gdm leads to 'Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused.'

Comment: @user776206 Hm, that's unexpected. I'll go play with it a bit later.